# Pentaho does not read sql script (csv)

Tags: mysql, database-design, scripting, parameter, pentaho

I was trying to use a different sql script for one job. For doing this i need to pass the script by file csv, so i set the script like a variable and then i make a transformation that "copy to row" for reading the parameter. I thought that pentaho did not read the script because when i tryed to extract paramenter he does not read anything.
Like i show below.
[image: This is the Transformation to configure]

[image: Inside CSV file input]

[image: Job after transformation to configure]
[image: Inside "Trasformazione leggi configurazione"]
[image: Inside "Trasformazione in CSV"]
[image: CSV file with the query]
[image: The error]

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Your question seems to a be a tool specific error. Are you inputting the correct values in the correct places? There might be an issue with the syntax. Could you provide more details in your question? Click [edit] and add them directly to your question. For example: What is the name of the tool you are using? What is the environment you are working in?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message it seems that the  program does not understand the definition of the file: `${Internal.Entry.Current.Directory}\config.csv`.

> ```
> Couldn't get filed info from [$(sql_script)]
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "$" Posizione: 1
> ```

Try omitting the $ in the file definition (first screenshot):

```
{Internal.Entry.Current.Directory}\config.csv`
```

I'm not Pentaho expert, but unless your file contains a `$` in the first line, then the error must lie in the definition of the parameter for the CSV file.